# NodeJS + TinyURL - adding items to a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, tinyurl

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how would I go about adding items into a list? So what I've got is a loop that basically runs through and tries to convert all the urls to tinyurls from a web **scraper** . It still produces an empty list for images_short. I'm not very familiar with nodejs's syntax. Here's a snippet of code, I've put some data in the images_long list:

```
const TinyURL = require('tinyurl');

var images_long = ['https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fhypebeast.com%2Fimage%2F2017%2F06%2Fadidas-skateboarding-lucas-premiere-adv-primeknit-khaki-0.jpg?fit=max&fm=pjpg&h=344&ixlib=php-1.1.0&q=90&w=516&s=728297932403d74d2ac1afa5ecdfa97d', 'https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fhypebeast.com%2Fimage%2F2017%2F06%2Fadidas-nmd-r1-stlt-triple-black-first-look-0.jpg?fit=max&fm=pjpg&h=344&ixlib=php-1.1.0&q=90&w=516&s=918752eba81826e4398950efc69a5141'];
var images_short = [];

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    TinyURL.shorten(images_long[i], function(res) {
        images_short.push(res[i]);
    });
}
```

I still get an empty list when I changed `images_short.push(res[i]);` to `images_short.push(res);`

Comment: `res` is a string, so just `images_short.push(res);` will do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res` is a string, so just `images_short.push(res);` will do the trick.   Also, you should iterate with respect to the length of the variable you're indexing, and you should `var` your indexing variable (`i`):

```
const TinyURL = require('tinyurl');

var images_long = [
    'https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fhypebeast.com%2Fimage%2F2017%2F06%2Fadidas-skateboarding-lucas-premiere-adv-primeknit-khaki-0.jpg?fit=max&fm=pjpg&h=344&ixlib=php-1.1.0&q=90&w=516&s=728297932403d74d2ac1afa5ecdfa97d',
    'https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fhypebeast.com%2Fimage%2F2017%2F06%2Fadidas-nmd-r1-stlt-triple-black-first-look-0.jpg?fit=max&fm=pjpg&h=344&ixlib=php-1.1.0&q=90&w=516&s=918752eba81826e4398950efc69a5141'];
var images_short = [];

for (var i = 0; i < images_long.length; i++) {
    TinyURL.shorten(images_long[i], function(res) {
        images_short.push(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting an empty list for images_short

Comment: The above code works at the command line because by the time you type `images_short`, the http calls have returned their value.  However, if you `console.log(images_short)` in the same block of code, the http calls have not yet had a chance to be executed.   In particular, in JavaScript (and nodeJS) [everything is asynchronous except your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338368/1519199).  Do an internet search for "understanding javascript callbacks" for more on this.

Comment: So if I wanted to show the new list (images_short), where would I put the console.log(images_short)?

Comment: Sorry, I mean like if wanted to use the list in another loop or something.

Comment: If you want to use the list in another loop, you'll have to wait until the list has been populated.  You could do this manually, but if you're serious about learning JS, you should check out the [BlueBird Promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-promises.html).   Gotta put my kids to bed so not gonna go into more detail....

Answer (score 0):

The tinyurl library is async.

Is we use native map, the resulting callback wouldn't be returned if we try to `console.log(images_short)` until all the links in the array have been shortened.

We can however, use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and specificically use `async.map` to return the results like the example below.

```
const TinyURL = require('tinyurl');
const async = require('async');

var images_long = [
    'https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fhypebeast.com%2Fimage%2F2017%2F06%2Fadidas-skateboarding-lucas-premiere-adv-primeknit-khaki-0.jpg?fit=max&fm=pjpg&h=344&ixlib=php-1.1.0&q=90&w=516&s=728297932403d74d2ac1afa5ecdfa97d',
    'https://hypebeast.imgix.net/http%3A%2F%2Fhypebeast.com%2Fimage%2F2017%2F06%2Fadidas-nmd-r1-stlt-triple-black-first-look-0.jpg?fit=max&fm=pjpg&h=344&ixlib=php-1.1.0&q=90&w=516&s=918752eba81826e4398950efc69a5141'];

function shorten(item, cb) {
  TinyURL.shorten(item, function(res) {
    cb(null, res);
  });
}

async.map(images_long, shorten, (err, results) => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

we can assign `images_short` if you want to keep consistency.